# Sort characters in a string alphabetically in a sentence

Tags: c

The problem that I'm having is sorting more than one word and case sensitivity.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int main() {
           char str[100], result[100], ch;
           int no[52] = {0}, n, c, t, x;
           printf("Enter a string: ");
           scanf("%[^\n]", str);
           n = strlen(str);

          //store how many times a-z characters appear in str
          for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
          ch = str[c] - 'a';
          no[c]++;
          }
          t = 0;

          //insert the characters a-z in output which contains characters
          //in alphabetical order
          for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
                  x = ch - 'a';
                  for (c = 0; c < no[x]; c++) {
                          result[t] = ch;
                          t++;
                  }
          }
          result[t] = '\0';
          printf("%s\n", result);
          return 0;
  }
```

**output: hello -> ehllo**

---

What I'm looking for is
 **output: Hello World From Ka -> eHllo dlorW Fmor aK**

---

Are there any libraries or functions that can make this easier?

Comment: Please remove the line numbers to improve the quality of the post.

Comment: Wong2, What does this line of code do `no[c]++;` for counting a-z characters?

Comment: (a) Asking for recommendations for software libraries is off-topic for Stack Overflow. (b) A library cannot make this problem easier because it is already very easy. (c) There are elementary errors in your code that must be fixed, such as calculating `ch` as `str[c] - 'a'` but then using `c` instead of `ch` to index the `no` array. Using external libraries requires mastering the basics of C; errors interacting with external software will be magnified, so it is essential to be able to get your own code correct first.

Comment: It is not a bad idea to count the occurrences of each letter. However, defining `no[52]` allows only for counting the uppercase and lowercase letters, but your code only calculates the index as `str[c] - 'a'`. That is a problem because the uppercase and lowercase letters are not adjacent in most encodings (like ASCII), so they span more than 52 values. You would have to calculate the index in a more complicated way or make more room in `no`. Also, the lowercase letters have higher codes than the uppercase letters in ASCII, so `str[c] - 'a'` is negative for uppercase letters.

Comment: It would be simpler to use the `unsigned char` type to handle characters and to declare `no` large enough to handle all of them, with `int no[UCHAR_MAX+1];`. Then you can simply use each character code as an index into the `no` array, without needing to do any arithmetic or other transformation on it. To get the definition of `UCHAR_MAX`, you will need `#include <limits.h>`.

Comment: If you get that working, it will output the uppercase letters followed by the lowercase letters (assuming your C implementation uses ASCII). Your example suggests you want to ignore the case. That can be a letter step; you could ask a new question after getting the initial code working.

Comment: Incomplete spec - e.g. `Heh, "Cheese"` -> `eHh, "Ceeehs"` or `,ehH ""Ceeehs`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use two iterators (a head and tail) and work on each "word" in place, one at a time.

Your sort order "should be" a case-insensitive sort, and you seem to have some code subtracting 'a' from each character to rebase/offset the value into your array. However, I don't see any code that converts upper-case characters to their lower-case equivalents (which is only necessary for sorting, based on your requirement, you should still be outputting the original upper-case character input.)

I am not seeing a reason to store a count of any characters in the string, possibly that could be removed, or clarified.

**Welcome to stack overflow.** One way to get improved responses and help with your questions is to include some details about what you are trying to do, and not just your code. If you *must* include code to convey your problem, consider breaking it down into separate chunks. Not only will this help us understand if you have more than one question (and boy will the community let you know!) but it will also help you understand how to simplify your questions to get better help and faster :) as this is written it may belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ site instead. It probably is not good Q&A for StackOverflow, again, as-is.

HTH!